# Windows Keeps crashing after boot

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, bsod

My math teacher gave me an old Windows XP computer a few years back and last year, There was a power surge in my home and the motherboard was just completely fried. I took the hard drive out. Today, I found a different computer and put my hard disk in that. It booted up fine until it got to the login screen. Then, It gave me a bsod with the code 0x0000007E. I went to safe mode with networking to download an error fix. Then, when I go hit login, it tells me that I need to activate windows outside of safe mode.

Can anyone tell me what to do?

edit: I have gotten into safe mode, found my product key and verified that it works. I just need to know how to activate it from within windows recovery console. Then, I can logon to safe mode with networking, install a blue screen fixer and reboot.

can anyone tell me how to activate it?

Comment: XP was tied to the other motherboard (OEM) which was fried. It was not retail. You will never get it to boot unless you activate. OPtions: Buy another XP license, Buy a newer version of Windows, Install a linux...

Comment: A newer version wont work with this hadware. Windows xp isn't supported, so I doubt i can buy a license. I wanted to use windows so I could use my game engines and visual c++ and stuff. It wouldn't let me register the key anyways because it will blue screen before it prompts me to do anything. Isn't there a way i can retreive the key from the old motherboard?

Comment: You need to boot to recovery console to activate. Like I said, OEM license is tied to motherboard. Your motherboard died, so you can NOT use that license with a new motherboard. Find a new RETAIL or OEM license (ebay).

Comment: The issue is the hard driver controller is different and has no driver.  You **might** be able to go into the BIOS and turn off AHCI and set it for the lowest legacy mode possible and it might load.  Now activation is a whole different question, if it is an OEM windows it still might not activate.

Comment: I am getting the blue screen because there was an unexpected shut down aka: the power surge. I just want to know how to get into the system past the blue screen.i have my product key written down from a tool that gets it from regedit. All, i need to do is get past blue screen.

Comment: I'm in the recovery console. I installed it via winnt32. I got the key from regedit. How to I activate windows? What do I do now?

Comment: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/ht/changexpkey.htm

Answer (score 0):

the blue screen is caused, because you're taking a windows drive, and putting it into a completely different PC to use. This is generally not recommended. It's better to completely reinstall windows. This should remove the blue screen.

This will allow you to login properly, and if your windows install is not tied to an OEM (OEM install means it was preinstalled on the old computer) then you should be able to call the number it gives you during activation, and switch the license to your new computer.

If it is an OEM install, you cannot use that install on any hardware other than the computer it came with.